# multiple Spike arrest policies in Apigee?

Tags: apigee

I just want to set 1ps for specific client that I will pass a header as Partner-ID. For other clients I want to use some other rate limit ex:5ps. How can I achieve this in Apigee using Spike Arrest?

Comment: Does this specific client have a developer app associated with it?

Comment: Yes we have same app for all the PartnerIDs. Only PartnerID will change.

Comment: One way would be to have a separate developer app created for each client. Configure a custom attribute to hold the spike arrest rate value and reference it in the spike arrest policy. Make sure the identifier is set to point to the app's client ID. That way you can set different rate depending on the client.